# Why does Lodash _.map return an array of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I am trying to use Lodash to return the key values of an array of objects.  Usually this works to return the values, but simply returns

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

The array of objects is created dynamically from an API, but there is nothing out of the ordinary about it I don't think.  It has the usual structure:

```
[object, object, object]
```

With

```
object = {
key: value
key: value
}
```

I am doing this in Angular 2.

## Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NewsApiService } from '../service/news-api.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { MapComponent } from '../map/map.component';

import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  private bbcJSON: any;
  private alJazeeraJSON: any;
  private bingWorldJSON: any;
  private bingPoliticsJSON: any;


  share(event) {
    console.log(_.map(this.bbcJSON, 'title'));
    console.log(event);
}
```

bbcJSON:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
author
:
"BBC News"
description
:
"The concern comes as the US takes a tough line on North Korea, which may test another nuclear device."
publishedAt
:
"2017-04-14T14:35:21Z"
title
:
"China fears North Korea-US conflict 'at any moment'"
url
:
"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-39600426"
urlToImage
:
"https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/A4F0/production/_95642224_mediaitem95642223.jpg"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
length
:
10
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: Does your object have a key named `title`?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  Yeah it has the title key.  I tried with other keys as well, but get the same result.

Comment: can you show **this.bbcJSON**?

Comment: Thanks.  I added the image link.

Comment: Please show code as text, not as an image. You should be able to copy and paste.

Comment: Test your _.map on custom data like [{test: 1, test: 2, .. etc}], I start thinking its somehow broked

Comment: I tried with some custom data and it returns an empty array.  hmmm.  I'm wondering if it could be because the object keys are not strings?